# Are there Webhooks for Google My Business (GMB)?

Tags: webhooks, google-my-business-api

Does Google offer webhooks for Google My Business (GMB)?

I don't see any mention in the official docs: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest
I have already "googled" this question.

Answer (score 1):

Google My Business does not support webhooks. Instead, you can set up real-time notifications using GCP Pub/Sub.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup